# Newtonsoft json parsing error

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Until now i was using c#  Newtonsoft json to parse graph api json responses. Everything was ok except when the text in the json response includes emoticons.

In that situation the json is not valid and the parsing stops.

is there any way to parse json with emoticons? do i have to convert them to something?

Comment: The JSON the API returns should always valid, even if the content has emojis somewhere in it. This sounds more like it might get messed up on your end?

Comment: i just copy paste the json response to jsonlint.com and always get error in the row that there is emoticons, if i remove it and vaildate again then no error appears

Comment: Please quote error messages verbatim, and show an example of the exact data this occurs with! Edit your question to include this minimum of useful information.